# Changing image on Hover in a shopify shop

Tags: hover, shopify

I have problems getting this to work. I want to change image on mouseover/hoover but I cant get this to work.

```
<div class="image_wrapper">
    <div class="image_main">
        <a href="{{ url }}">          
             <img src="{% if product.images.size >= 1%}{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large' }}{% else %}{{ 'No_Image_2.png' | asset_url }}{% endif %}" alt="{{ product.title | escape  }}" />
        </a>
    </div>

{% if product.images.size > 1 %}
   <div class="image_main_hover">
       <img class="hidden" src="{{ product.images[1] | product_img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.images[1].alt | escape }}" />
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did in a shopify store. I had to do this way cause his images were different in sizes but he want them all to be same size.

```
<div class="imgs" style="background-image: url('{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}');">
    {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
          <div class="imgs2" style="background-image: url('{{ product.images[1] | product_img_url: 'grande' }}')"></div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

css

```
.imgs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imgs2 {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.imgs:hover .imgs2 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `product-thumbnail.liquid`

Update below code:

```
<div class="reveal">
  <img src="{{ featured.featured_image.src | img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ featured.featured_image.alt | escape }}"><!-- this is your original image tag -->
  <div class="hidden">
    <img src="{{ product.images.last | img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.images.last.alt | escape }}" />
    <div class="caption">
      <div class="centered">
        YOUR TEXT
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is css:

```
.reveal .hidden { display: block !important; visibility: visible !important;}
.product:hover .reveal img { opacity: 1; }
.reveal { position: relative; }
.reveal .hidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;  
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}
.reveal:hover .hidden { 
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;    
}
.reveal .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;  
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white; /* fallback for IE8 */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  font: 13px/1.6 sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.reveal .hidden .caption .centered {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .reveal .caption { 
    font-size: 11px; 
  }
}
```